# Adding click listeners in a loop for Revolution Slider

Tags: jquery, revolution-slider

I'm using the Revolution Slider plugin for Wordpress.  Rev Slider provides an api for changing slides or listening for events.  Underneath the slider wrapper I'm dynamically adding a link to each slide using `<a id="<?php echo "rev-slide-".$vid_link ?>" href="#"><?php echo $link ?></a>` where $vid_link is an incrementing integer and $link is some text entered into a custom field.  What I want to do in my script file is add a click listener to each link that will access the rev slider api to change the slide.  So far I've tried the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    //...

    if(typeof revapi1 === 'undefined') return;

    revapi1.bind('revolution.slide.onloaded', function() {
        var totalSlides = revapi1.revmaxslide();

        var changeSlide = function(x) {
            revapi1.revshowslide(x);
        }

        for (var i = 2; i <= totalSlides; i++) {
            jQuery("#rev-slide-" + i).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                changeSlide(i);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here revapi1 is the var name given to the particular slider.  I was having scope issues with calling revshowslide() using the for loop variable directly from within the loop itself.  I tried wrapping the api call in a separate function, but it's still receiving only the final value of i.  Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the "i"-variable is not available in your click-function, you could pass it like so:

```
jQuery("#rev-slide-" + i).click({myInt : i}function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        changeSlide(e.data.myInt);
 });
```